# Stdin and argument into shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

How do I pass an argument as well as stdin into a program using a shell script?

If I have the data, how do I select only the numbered columns and input it into my program "./calculate < data" as stdin?

data:

```
ajk:1,2,3,4
bcd:8,9,3,1
```

Answer (score 0):

One sort of clunky way:

```
./calculate < awk -F '[:, ]' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}' data
```

Your script can then use a loop which reads from stdin by default:

```
while read v1 v2 v3 v4
do
# do stuff with four variables here
done
```

You can also directly parse the input inside the loop.  I will leave that for someone else to post.  Since you did not indicate your shell - bash, ksh ....

Comment: @jin sorry I'm using bash.
If I also called in an argument intially ie.
./calc.sh data.txt 2 3 4 5
where 2 3 4 5 are the arguments and data.txt is the stdin data how do I differentiate these within my code?

Comment: Neither.  data.txt and 2 3 4 5 are all shell parameters: $1, $2, $3, $4, $5.  data.txt is NOT stdin.   You have to redirect (use a pipe |  or a redirection operator  < or > to get stdin to be data.txt, otherwise stdin is your keyboard device.